# send post from JsonArrayRequest volley to server not working

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I already tried some example about send post from JsonArrayRequest volley to server, but it's not working and no have error in log..

so when I call a post in server the post can't get and my data when not call post is show, but now when call post, the data not show

this the code

```
public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL() {
            CustomJsonArrayRequest request = new CustomJsonArrayRequest (GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                            JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("name", "value");
                    return params;
                }
            };
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

and this the code for new class

```
    public class CustomJsonArrayRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONArray> {

        public CustomJsonArrayRequest(String url, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener);
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", "value");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            try {
                String jsonString =
                        new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
            }
        }
    }

after webcall

public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            GetDataAdapterRiwayat GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapterRiwayat();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {

                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                GetDataAdapter2.setIdJalanRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_ID_JALAN));
                GetDataAdapter2.setNamaJalanRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_NAMA_JALAN));
                GetDataAdapter2.setLatitudeRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_LATITUDE));
                GetDataAdapter2.setLongitudeRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_LONGITUDE));
                GetDataAdapter2.setFotoSebelumRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_FOTO_SEBELUM));
                GetDataAdapter2.setFotoSetelahRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_FOTO_SETELAH));
                GetDataAdapter2.setIdRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_ID_RIWAYAT));

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }

        recyclerViewadapterRiwayat = new RecyclerViewAdapterRiwayat(GetDataAdapter1, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapterRiwayat);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `GET` if `POST` still not working

example

```
CustomJsonArrayRequest request = new CustomJsonArrayRequest (GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL + "?&name=value",
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
```

and change in class `CustomJsonArrayRequest`

```
super(Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener);
```

with

```
super(Method.GET, url, null, listener, errorListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL() {

    Map<String, Object> jsonParams = new HashMap<>();
    jsonParams.put("name", "value");

    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,

            new JSONObject(jsonParams),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    Log.e("Res", response.toString());

                    // Do your stuff here

                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //   Handle Error
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("User-agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"));
            return headers;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}



public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(String response) {

    try {

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            GetDataAdapterRiwayat GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapterRiwayat();

            JSONObject json = null;

            try {

                json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                GetDataAdapter2.setIdJalanRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_ID_JALAN));
                GetDataAdapter2.setNamaJalanRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_NAMA_JALAN));
                GetDataAdapter2.setLatitudeRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_LATITUDE));
                GetDataAdapter2.setLongitudeRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_LONGITUDE));
                GetDataAdapter2.setFotoSebelumRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_FOTO_SEBELUM));
                GetDataAdapter2.setFotoSetelahRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_FOTO_SETELAH));
                GetDataAdapter2.setIdRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_ID_RIWAYAT));

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }

        recyclerViewadapterRiwayat = new RecyclerViewAdapterRiwayat(GetDataAdapter1, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapterRiwayat);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

> Edited Answer

```
public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL() {

    String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = "http://jalanrusak.16mb.com/AndroidFileUpload/GetDataRiwayat.php";

    Map<String, Object> jsonParams = new HashMap<>();
    jsonParams.put("name", "value");

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

    JsonArrayRequest postRequest= new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            Log.e("Res", response.toString());
            JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response.toString());

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //   Handle Error
            Log.e("Res", error.toString());
        }
    });

    queue.add(postRequest);
}

public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(String response) {

    try {

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            GetDataAdapterRiwayat GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapterRiwayat();

            JSONObject json = null;

            try {

                json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                GetDataAdapter2.setIdJalanRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_ID_JALAN));
                GetDataAdapter2.setNamaJalanRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_NAMA_JALAN));
                GetDataAdapter2.setLatitudeRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_LATITUDE));
                GetDataAdapter2.setLongitudeRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_LONGITUDE));
                GetDataAdapter2.setFotoSebelumRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_FOTO_SEBELUM));
                GetDataAdapter2.setFotoSetelahRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_FOTO_SETELAH));
                GetDataAdapter2.setIdRiwayat(json.getString(JSON_ID_RIWAYAT));

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }

        recyclerViewadapterRiwayat = new RecyclerViewAdapterRiwayat(GetDataAdapter1, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapterRiwayat);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: it's error on `Response` when I call ` JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);` because your code is jsonobject not jsonarray

Comment: You need to modify your JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response); method

Comment: Can you share your JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response); method here, so I can edit it

Comment: Post your response

Comment: what response?.

Comment: Which you are getting in onResponse method. JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);

Comment: mmm if I'm not wrong understand.. the response is from server the form json like this http://pastebin.com/PX7Qsvsf

Comment: still error in `JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);` the error is `JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(java.lang.string) to org.json.JSONObject`

Comment: Can you share your GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL - url and param, i will test it in Android studio

Comment: this `String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = "http://jalanrusak.16mb.com/AndroidFileUpload/GetDataRiwayat.php";` and param is just like my post

Comment: try this http://jalanrusak.16mb.com/AndroidFileUpload/GetDataRiwayat.php

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
public class BaseRequest extends Request<JSONArray> {
    private static final String TAG = BaseRequest.class.getSimpleName();
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();


    private final Response.Listener listener;

    public BaseRequest(String url, Response.Listener responseListener, Response.ErrorListener listener) {
        super(Request.Method.GET, url, listener);
        Log.e(TAG, "Requesting url : " + url);
        this.listener = responseListener;
    }
    public BaseRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener responseListener, Response.ErrorListener listener) {
        super(method, url, listener);
        Log.e(TAG, "Requesting url : " + url);
        this.listener = responseListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

        try {
            String json = null;
            json = new String(
                    response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            JSONArray result = new JSONArray(json);

           return Response.success(
                        result,
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));

        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {

            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            e.pri

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        return volleyError;
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONArray response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }


}
```

and make request:

```
BaseRequest baseRequest = new BaseRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                //Response as JsonArray
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error : " + error.getMessage());

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

               //Your parameters
                return params;
            }
        };

queue.add(baseRequest);
```

Comment: how I can use `public void onResponse(Object response) {` because my response as JsonArray like this `JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);` , so the `response` is error because is object not array

Comment: I am updating my answer.. Please wait